# iOS Passing (Retain) the value of an NSMutableArray to another NSMutableArray in another view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using .XIB and without ARC. I'm passing the value of the NSMultableArray to another view, if I put [self presentModel...], it works, but if I call the AnotherView with a button the value of the NSMultableArray of the AnotherView is null!

*AnotherView.h*

```
@interface AnotherViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,      UITableViewDelegate>{
NSMutableArray *otherAnother;
NSMutableArray *arrayOfTheAnotherView;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayOfTheAnotherView;
```

*AnotherView.m*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

otherAnother = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
otherAnother = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.arrayOfTheAnotherView];
//    [otherAnother addObjectsFromArray:arrayOfTheAnotherView]; 
NSLog(@"%@", self.arrayOfTheAnotherView);
}
```

The NSLog has written "null"

*CurrentView.h*

```
@interface CurrentViewController : UIViewController {
NSMutableArray * arrayCurrentView;
AnotherViewController *superAnotherView;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) AnotherViewController *superAnotherView;
```

*CurrentView.m*

```
@synthesize superAnotherView;
NSString *x = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[label text]];

arrayCurrentView = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[arrayCurrentView retain];
[arrayCurrentView addObject:x];

self.superAnotherView = [[AnotherViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.superAnotherView.arrayOfTheAnotherView = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self.superAnotherView.arrayOfTheAnotherView retain];
[self.superAnotherView.arrayOfTheAnotherView addObjectsFromArray:arrayCurrentView];
```

I don't know how to retain the value of the NSMultableArray, thanks the help.

It is how I call the AnotherView:

```
UIButton *buttonAnother = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; [buttonAnother  setTag:5]; [buttonAnother addTarget:self action:@selector(switchTabBar:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]; 
[tabBarViewController.view addSubview:buttonAnother];
- (IBAction)switchTabBar:(id)sender { switch ([(UIButton *)sender tag]) { case 5:     [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; break; }
```

Comment: try a data storage:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448476/objective-c-singleton-objects-and-global-variables or http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Answer (score 0):

These should not be necessary:

```
self.superAnotherView.arrayOfTheAnotherView = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
[self.superAnotherView.arrayOfTheAnotherView retain];
```

Properties are already initialized when the class is initialized.

In fact, your explicit retain lines shouldn't be necessary at all; you're not releasing them as far as I can see and just making the retain count 2 so that it has to be released twice.

I think there's something going on here that the methods and view controllers are not being called in the order you want, probably something to do with the tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

I dicoverd! I'm using the MVC
A array of the APP delegate don't lost its value.
AppDelegate
    NSMutableArray *arrayDelegate;
View.m
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [appDelegate.arrayDelegatePedido addObject:@"title"]; //for example