# How to use NSMutableArray from Master Controller in Detail Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using UISplitViewController and I have a Master Controller and Detail Controller.

The Master Controller I have a NSMutableArray defined like so:

```
#import "MasterController.h"
#import "DetailController.h"

@interface MasterController ()

@property NSMutableArray *objects;
@end

@implementation MasterController
```

and I am trying to call it in my Detail Controller like so:

```
#import "DetailController.h"
#import "MasterController.h"

@interface DetailController ()
{
     MasterController *purchaseOrder;
}

@end

@implementation DetailController

- (void)GetRequest
{

    NSArray *tableData = [dataSource.areaData GetPurchaseOrderItems:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",areaPickerSelectionString,unitPickerSelectionString]];
    NSLog(@"%@", tableData);
    //TODO: foreach tableData populate object.
    [purchaseOrder object];

}
```

ultimately I am looking to populate the object with each item in tableData. But when I call object, I get this error:

```
No visible @interface for 'LHPurchaseOrderMaster' declares the selector 'object'
```

how would I accomplish what I am trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C Singleton Objects and Global Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448476/objective-c-singleton-objects-and-global-variables) and [Global variable NSMuteableArray using Singleton Class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5795997/608639)

Comment: I dont understand how these will help

Comment: this is not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many things amiss here.  A few short pointers to hopefully help:

You've put `@property NSMutableArray *objects;` in your private interface.  Try moving this to the header file and making it public.  Any reason why you haven't declared this as `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objects;`  ?

The syntax `[someInstance someMethod]` means that your `purchaseOrder` instance of `MasterController` is trying to call a method called `object` of which you've not provided us any details about.  Perhaps you're trying to call `objects` instead.  But this will only work if you make it public as noted above.

If you're attempting to design a better API than that, you can keep your `NSMutableArray` of `objects` private, and provide a public `NSArray` of maybe `*allObjects` and inside your`DetailController` a getter method like

```
- (NSArray*)allObjects {
    return [self.objects copy];
}
```

You've not provided any information about `LHPurchaseOrderMaster`, but hopefully I'm on the right track with helping you solve your problem here.