# Does Xcode force MVC design pattern by default?

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOs development and want to follow the correct design pattern, but it looks like Xcode forces the user of MVC design pattern by default.

I have the model (MyApp.h)
You have a view (where I can drag & drop components)
And I have a controller (MyApp.m)

Is this the correct way of thinking?

Thanks

Comment: No, the `.h` is a header will and not a model. A model is a class that holds information, the controller will bind the data from the model to a view. I would suggest you read up on `MVC` and then the docs on iOS development on http://developer.apple.com

Comment: this may answer on your questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227904/organizing-ios-project-for-mvc-design-pattern?rq=1

Comment: xcode is an IDE only anyways, objC doesnt enforce it but apple strongly pushes you towards it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll go with a very basic example.

You want to display a list of people, with their name, age and location, like this :

```
Bob    32    United States
Paul   22    England
Jack   24    France
...
```

Here, you will create a new class, inheriting from `NSObject`, which you will call `Person`. Your class will consist of a header file (.h) and implementation file (.m). It will have properties, to hold the different elements of your "real" person, and methods to access and/or work on them (get the name, increment the age, change the location). This is your **model**.

Then, you will use a subclass of `UITableViewController`, called `CustomTableViewController`, to present the data. This is your **controller**.

The **view** is in fact the `tableView` contained in your `UITableViewController`.

The basics behind the MVC pattern is that your `CustomTableViewController` is responsible for the communication between the `tableView` and your `Person` objects. And this happens in the implementation of your `tableViewController`, the file `CustomTableViewController.m`.

Your `tableViewController` will (for example) create an array of `Person` objects, get all the data from somewhere, create the `Person`s, store them into the array, etc.

Then, `UITableViewController`s (and their subclasses, of course), implement a delegate method called `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, which the `tableView` calls when it needs to display a cell. The `tableViewController` creates a `cell`, populates it with the data, and hands the cell to the `tableView`. This is how you handle the communication. You don't ask directly to your `tableView` to go get the data.

This also works backwards. If your `tableView` allows editing, it will inform the `tableViewController` of the user interactions, and it's the role of the latter to reflect the modifications on your **model**.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. It would be good to read about it from Apple's documentation:

Start with: [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)
and then you can go deeper into it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode doesn't "force MVC". It's best practice and Apple makes it easy to do, but one of the key concepts in MVC is the separation of the model object from the view and view controller objects, but this proper isolation is achieved solely through programmer discipline, not through the tool.

Regardless, I'd suggest you refer to Apple's primer on [Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) in the *Cocoa Core Competencies* guide. There are lots of good links on that page.