# is it ok to retain the delegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory, delegates

I have stumbled upon a problem in my application where my music player view controller needs to retain the delegate (which is a cloud based storage with songs) to keep the song playlist, until the song from a new folder is selected.

So, when the user taps a song in some folder, I assign the delegate to that ViewController so even when it is pushed from the view, it stays in the memory so the music player can play next and previous songs. But when the user selects the song from another folder(ViewController), I set the music player delegate to nil, and assign the delegate to that new ViewController.

Is this solution acceptable?

Code:

MusicPlayerViewController has:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <MusicPlayerViewDelegate> delegate;
```

View Controller in which the songs will be loaded from cloud storage folders has this called when tapped on cell(song):

```
musicPlayerViewController.delegate = nil;
musicPlayerViewController.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fundamental problem with retaining (holding a strong reference to) a delegate. It is unusual, but not unprecedented. `NSURLConnection` does it. It creates a retain loop that can be very useful if correctly managed. It's just up to you to make sure that the object will release its delegate in a deterministic way so that the retain loop is broken.

BUT... the specific case that you're discussing here sounds like you have an MVC problem and that your view controller is doing something it shouldn't be.

> I assign the delegate to that ViewController so even when it is pushed from the view, it stays in the memory so the music player can play next and previous songs.

If you're saying that you cannot play music unless a certain view controller is in memory, then the view controller probably has an incorrect responsibility. The view controller should manage the view. That should be independent of actually playing music. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5228317/97337 for discussion of how a music-playing system might be broken out in MVC.

Comment: Thanks for advice, the ViewController that stays in the memory is a DropboxViewController which pulls data from Dropbox storage, and creates streamable links for player, that's why it is hard for me to create some smart MVC pattern, do you have some ideas maybe?

Comment: If they designed their view controller to manage its own network traffic, that's unfortunate. There may not be much you can do to fix it. They should have a `DropboxController` that's separate from the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you are proposing, the delegate should be actually weak considering the music player stays as the same instances and the view controller gets set / unset to something different.

If the delegate were strong, your Viewcontroller will not get released unless the Musicplayer gets deallocated and in most cases a Viewcontroller should get released when it's view is no longer in use. As Rob mentioned, you seem to have a MVC problem.